# QT creator Linux ошибка компиляции

Tags: c++, linux, c, qt

Пишу код в Qtcreator на Linux подключены библиотеки "safelib С" для работы bounds-checking при компиляции пишет ошибку

**ошибка: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘rsize_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-fpermissive]
     strcpy_s(m_Model, Model); 
                           ^

И ошибка

ошибка: too few arguments to function ‘errno_t strcpy_s(char*, rsize_t, const char*)’

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <safe_lib.h>
#include <safe_lib_errno.h>
#include <safe_mem_lib.h>
#include <safe_types.h>
#include <safe_str_lib.h>
using namespace std;
Weapon::Weapon() :
    m_pName(new char[1]),
    m_Power(0),
    m_Calibre(0)
{
    *m_pName = '\0'; m_Model[0] = '\0';
}

Weapon::Weapon(const char* Name, int Power, const char* Model, int Calibre) :
    m_pName(new char[strlen(Name) + 1]),
    m_Power(Power),
    m_Calibre(Calibre)
{
    strcpy_s(m_pName, strlen(Name) + 1, Name);
    strcpy_s(m_Model, Model); ------- тут ошибка
}
Weapon :: Weapon (const Weapon& Wep) :
    m_pName (new char [strlen (Wep.m_pName) + 1]),
    m_Power (Wep.m_Power),
    m_Calibre (Wep.m_Calibre) {
    strcpy_s (m_pName, strlen (Wep.m_pName) + 1, Wep.m_pName);
    strcpy_s (m_Model, Wep.m_Model, ) ;
}

Weapon:: ~Weapon()
{
    delete m_pName;
}

void Weapon :: setName (const char* pName) {
    delete [ ] m_pName ;
    m_pName = new char [strlen (pName) + 1] ;
    strcpy_s (m_pName, strlen (pName) + 1, pName) ;}


void Weapon::setModel(const char* Model) 
{
    strcpy_s(m_Model, Model, );
}
void Weapon::setPower(int Power) 
{
    m_Power = Power;
}
void Weapon::setCalibre(int Calibre)
{
    m_Calibre = Calibre;
}

char* Weapon :: getName ( ) const {
    return m_pName;}

char* Weapon :: getModel ( ) const 
{
    return const_cast <char*> (m_Model) ;
}
int Weapon::getPower() const 
{
    return m_Power;
}
int Weapon::getCalibre() const 
{
    return m_Calibre;
}


bool Weapon :: checkName (const char* p) const
{
    return ! strcmp (m_pName, p) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке прямым текстом написано, что strcpy_s принимает 3 аргумента, а не 2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/td1esda9.aspx

Comment: В том то и дело, что в windows visual все нормально даже без этого 3 аргумента(в унике проверял), а qtcreator на Linux системе ему нужен 3 аргумент и я не пойму какой вписать

Comment: @keshaalekseeev: Логично, что вторым параметром идет strlen(Model) - длина третей строки, по аналогии с предыдущими. Откуда то её же нужно узнать, не все строки завершаются нулём.

Answer (score 0):

```
errno_t strcpy_s(  
   char *strDestination,  // <- Куда копировать
   size_t numberOfElements,  // <- Размер строкового буфера назначения в единицах char для узкой и многобайтовых функций и в единицах wchar_t для расширенных функций (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/td1esda9.aspx)
   const char *strSource // <- откуда
);
```

Далее перегруженная шаблонная функция с двумя параметрами.
Работает аналагично, если я правильно понял, но только там, где поддерживается c++. И второй параметр уходит в шаблон - это максимальный размер строкового буффера, использующийся при копировании.

```
template <size_t size>  
errno_t strcpy_s(  
   char (&strDestination)[size],  
   const char *strSource   
); // C++ only
```

Итого, если у вас поддерживается C++ (Что вероятно) надо делать так:

```
size_t len = strlen (Model)
strcpy_s<len>(m_Model, Model);
```

Или так, что одно и тоже.

```
size_t len = strlen (Model)
strcpy_s(m_Model, len, Model);
```

Приблизительно так.